# SpoonX Aurelia Form v1.1.5 entity-form and select element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am using aurelia-form v1.1.5 entity-form with the select element, but I am unsure how to populate the selectOptions property. I have tried numerous methods all coming up short. Was wondering if anyone had experience with this library. Could not find anything in their docs https://aurelia-form.spoonx.org/component/entity-form.html

```
import { element } from 'aurelia-form';

export class Foo {
 @element('select')
 types;
}

export class BarViewModel {
  contructor() {
    this.entity = new Foo();
  }
}
```

**Bar View**

`<template><entity-form entity.bind="entity"></entity-form></template>`

Comment: I don't have a computer to verify this right now, but it seems like you should use the @options decorator on for that - https://aurelia-form.spoonx.org/decorators.html#options

Comment: that was one of my methods i forgot to mention (sorry i was going to list them in my post, but i forgot) `@options({selectOptions: [{default:'default', success:'success']})`, but now that i think about it I wonder if I have to use the property `id` or `name` property.

Comment: I'll have to look and experiment again once I get home in a couple of hours. I have my ideas, but nothing verified.

Comment: yea and I had to move forward and ditch that version for now and request they bring `schemaform` back. I probably won't be able to test until later this week, but will check back here if you are able to answer

Comment: So I took another look at the sources. It appears that while `form-group` has `selectOptions`, there is neither a decorator to set it, nor does it get passed on by `entity-form`. So, not possible right now with entity-form but very much when building `aurelia-form` manually.

Comment: thanks for the research/confirmation. I also see you beat me to submitting an issue on GitHub, thanks!. if you want to put that as the answer for now I can give you credit.